# How to create local hotspot on raspberry pi 3b to share files on android

Tags: pi-3, wifi, pi-3b+, hotspot

I want create a local file shareable service using raspberry, below are the requirements:

1. Create wifi/hotspot on raspberry (without any internet)
2. Connect my android phone to created wifi
3. Share files between raspberry and my phone

Think any file sharable app like xender or share it, their working principle is same as I want.

Below are steps I've follow and created a wifi named PI-Network..

1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

2) https://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

But its not getting connected/ obtaining ip as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Go for it. Let us know if you encounter any problems we can help with.

Comment: @MarkSmith please look into this..

Answer (score 2):

**To enable Wifi Hotspot, you can look into**

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

and

https://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

**To share file, You can use Apps like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)**

The SFTP option in ES File Explorer lets you share files between Devices.

Some Short Notes of its usage

**Connect Your Android Phone to the Raspberry Pi Wi-Fi**

- Open ES File Explorer
- Select Menu
- Select Network
- Select FTP
- Select New
- Select SFTP

Then in the window that opens

- In Server put IP Address of your Raspberry PI (192.168.0.1
  for example)
- Leave Port as 22
- In Username enter your RaspberryPi Login username
- In Password enter your RaspberryPi login password
- Leave Encoding as auto
- In Display As choose any name you wish
- Press OK

Now You should be able to access the files in RaspberryPi

**NOTE:**

- You can use ES file Explore even if you just normally connect
  Raspberry Pi to your Android Mobile Hotspot. All that matters is
  Android Phone and RaspberryPi should be on same netwrok.
- Make sure **SSH** is enabled and installed in RaspberyrPI to use this option. To know about ssh check [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md)

Comment: Thanks @Karan, will try your way and provide feedback soon.. :)

Comment: Hello Karan, 
I've tried both the ways as per the instruction and was able to create a wifi but its not getting connect, please have a look at below ss:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7697097/55130221-0ed35b00-5140-11e9-9fed-8c1b34437fc2.png

Please let me know how to fix this..

[link] (https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7697097/55130221-0ed35b00-5140-11e9-9fed-8c1b34437fc2.png)

Comment: please look into this

Comment: Which solution among those two worked for you? While Attempting those steps did you face any problem or things went smoothly as per the instructions? Has the IP address been assigned to raspberry Pi? Check with `ifconfig`

Comment: 2) `https://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot` worked for me and no ip assigned, when I check by usinf `ifconfig`

Comment: Try restarting dhcpd service with `sudo service udhcpd restart ` and then check for the IP address.  If that doesnt work try manually assigning IP address to Rpi with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.42.1' and check it.

Comment: Check the status of  dnsmasq with  `systemctl status dnsmasq.service`. If its running stop it with `sudo service dnsmasq stop`. Post to this restart dhcpd with previous command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91639/discussion-between-ershakiransari-and-karan).

Comment: Failed to start dnsmasq - a lightweight dhcp and caching dns server